# Filtering Content search webpart in sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have got all the sub-site names in a CSWP, Now I need to implement filtering on it.
I have added a text filter web-part, but how to pass the parameter from this text filter web-part to CSWP?

Comment: cant you use the search box webpart ?

Comment: yes but it will bring result from everywhere, is it possible that search box only filters the data that I have in CSWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When add the content search webpart, you can ensure that the search box webpart is associated to it as below:

It would be `{SearchBoxQuery} your query to fetch sub site names`

[image]

After that, it will search within the content search webpart only.

Comment: yes this works, can you please tell me how we add icons to this as it shows images with no icon by default

Comment: cool (y), you need to change the item display template to `Two lines`. Check this excellent link - http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/03/displaying-right-data-in-content-search.html,  i would suggest that you copy the `Two lines` display template and create your own template and then apply it

Comment: Please mark it as answer if this helped resolve your issue :)